# Sort mixed array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a mixed array which i need to sort non-numeric values first then the numeric values.

Here is the data I have

```
[{Description:"c"},{Description:"a"},{Description:"1"},{Description:"b"},{Description:"2"},{Description:"11"}]
```

I'd like to have the sorted output as
a
b
c
1
2
11

What I've tried:

(Utils.Inue checks if null)

```
 .sort(function(a, b) {
return Utils.Inue(parseFloat(a.Description!)) || Utils.Inue(b.Description!) ? a.Description! < b.Description! ? -1 : a.Description! > b.Description! ?1 : 0 :  parseFloat(a.Description!) - parseFloat(b.Description!);
})
```

but the output turns out to be 1 2 11 a b c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with this code:

```
.sort(function(a,b){
if(isNaN(+a.Description!) && !isNaN(+b.Description!))
{
    return -1;
}
else if(!isNaN(+a.Description!) && isNaN(+b.Description!))
{
    return 1;
}
else if(!isNaN(+a.Description!) && !isNaN(+b.Description!))
{
    return parseFloat(a.Description!)>parseFloat(b.Description!) ? 1 : parseFloat(a.Description!) == parseFloat(b.Description!) ? 0 : -1 ;
}
else
{
     return a.Description!>b.Description! ? 1 : a.Description! == b.Description! ? 0 : -1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check the value for being finite and sort numbers to bottom.

```js
const
    array = [{ Description: "c" }, { Description: "a" }, { Description: "11" }, { Description: "b" }, { Description: "2" }, { Description: "1" }];
    
array.sort(({ Description: a }, { Description: b }) =>
    isFinite(a) - isFinite(b) ||
    a - b ||
    +(a > b) || -(a < b)
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nina. How can I use this in typescript? I'm getting Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number error since it expects 1,0 or -1.

Comment: please try above with unary plus for the first comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj=[{Description:"c"},{Description:"a"},{Description:"1"},{Description:"b"},{Description:"2"},{Description:"11"}];


var sortArray=(obj.sort((a,b)=>{
   let res=0
  if(!isNaN(a.Description)){
     return (+a.Description)-(+b.Description);
  }else{
    if (a.Description > b.Description) {
    res= 1;
  } else if (a.Description < b.Description) {
    res= -1;
  } 
  }
 

  return res;
}));

console.log(sortArray);
```

You can try this.
[Live Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UA6AQzwHMz4BXAOwBMA6UHTBQDOoIRVQphoeqGjxUAWABQIWRQDWKMpw4UOTaf0IlyVGgVYArSLBp6xXFDIDukAEag3rZ0MhkeysqqAih0jCzs3KCI9Joi4qCQ9EJ4oABm8GSgeOxoGEL0aTCpkAAeRJTIHIoqYM7imKAUjslNHEZEpJTUnqkx6noGCaiUAG4U9NB5opj0ZJBBYKjYvrRWNqhCfCGgAKoASgAy6ZlYUgT0TJIikKN%20eMuDi6DzAI5sFPNc03L038uhda2E5ZIRISDwDgoGC%20AK1dBkdDCBZKQKopRpTi2CiQ9J6LjETKoQYAQTIZEYAAoAJQAbzRylGc1A8DclgAvABtWkAEUgQlM1BxHAAXAAiWBigC%20ABpefzBcTIeL6NK5XyBd0laKxQBGNXyzVmYXitwGjWKk1igBM5oVWqtuv1UoAugBuBlKJmgolkil4dmU1mWHhgxGUyn0GVuansgB89KUoGT0EgNHmQnZAAZlMmKGlKQBCYQAOXoJcjPAtDsh1LpueTyfmqDYZHalIA1PQq-bjbWALSdtw9o1C2sepOgKUwyCJgCQ%20dAlerffacc8I8ttdAicbL357NAuonyaliWgq0Xy97Y-aAB4Nyvb9Sdw2mwfQP3jw2zz-c2j3xbNt9yECcpTrCdlAQDgwVTHg5CYSkw1QP1GGpSD0TREBm1bdoAFl6GWHgYlKSkeHIjM2GgVAeE0PAhBpdDlClT0oMhWDIHg%20BELSfFCURUlySpCDnhLeBnCwQjslyWY7mkdpmiSFk0lATBxKwUIGGYVhOG%20ZxMnUIQZWeVNUAAchEOR4HUaQaDUiT8E6RVoliflQH0sgBn0dyGmeAApegmS6MxokyFBMQ4PgeVbQYzhEXxsVxVwzOgKY3BQEY8CeWppk0SACGkERYDkVZ0FAJldFSmQAqC5zWgIeAhDENxUzyZ4hHs1T1JyNhQFgeh2nmfs2FWMphGJbz1A4cTUy4K44RAZ4AGFoAoWAbPSuQJLK6CJrYSARUWZ4ynoRA6AO4MNiEfsBq4G6hPooA)